# React application deployment with Laravel API in Apache Centos

Tags: reactjs, laravel, apache, deployment, httpd.conf

I have a react js application with connecting API in Laravel. Everything is working fine in localhost. When I'm trying to host this application in my apache server I'm facing a problem.

Trying to achieve the below configuration:

1. My domain for react application is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
2. My domain for Laravel application is [www.example.com/api](http://www.example.com/api)

**For this above URL set up**

1. document root folder : /var/www/html
2. react folder : /var/www/html/react/build
3. laravel folder : /var/www/html/app/

My virtual host configuration is

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # Client React application
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/react/build"
    ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine on
    
    # Server Laravel 7 API application
    Alias /api /var/www/html/app/public/
    SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    # Rewrite all requests in /api to server index.php
    <Location /api>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /api/index.php [L]
    </Location>
    <Directory "/var/www/html/app/public/">
            AllowOverride All
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<virtualhost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</virtualhost>
```

Created .htaccess in /var/www/html/.htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

I'm getting error like 'The requested URL was not found on this server.'

Please help me. what I'm doing wrong in this configuration.
The same configuration is working for angular.

Comment: If you found a solution, I have a similar issue :/